# What is the meaning of 'just enough'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is the meaning of 'just enough' in the following context:

People in richer countries, who use over 250 litres per person a day, will have to use less. Even 20–40 litres a day per person, which is **just enough** for basic human needs, can be difficult to find in many places.

Does it mean 'hardly sufficient' or 'quite/totally/perfectly enough'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly (or close to) the minimum required amount, but no more.

For clarification, **hardly sufficient** actually means **not sufficient**, usually used to emphasise the *not* part.

> "You'll have £10 a day to cover food and water"
>
> "£10? That's hardly enough!"

**quite/totally/perfectly enough** means **enough**, but with emphasis that it is not near the minimum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is clear for me now.

Answer (score 0):

"Just enough" means enough but no more than that. e.g.:

> She had just enough money to pay for her bus ticket.